# Save Variables from a .txt File on C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, variables

sorry I´m new with C# and working with Visual Studio. I´m trying to make a .txt with variables so later when I need to change for example a number o a path I can change it on the .txt file and don´t need to open the code and update.

For example I have this archive.txt

```
Joe;Rodriguez;C:\example\hello.txt;398663
```

And this is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] split;
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(@"C:\folder\archive.txt");
        string line;

        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            split = line.Split(new Char[] { ';' });
            string name = split[0];
            string lastname = split[1];
            string path = split[2];
            string num = split[3];

            Console.WriteLine("Split 0 is: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine("Split 2 is: " + lastname);
            Console.WriteLine("Split 3 is: " + path);
            Console.WriteLine("Split 4 is: " + num);

        }
    }

}
```

What it does, is that each value saves on a variable so after I can use it on the code. It is getting the value after the sign "**;**"

[values get save on variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rt0Vr.jpg)

How can I save the variables if my .txt file is saved like this:

[.txt File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffklb.jpg)

At the begining the .txt Dile is in one line and separated by a "**;**" what I want to do is that the program only saves the value aftes the "**= (space)**" and not being a line but with an enter on each line.

Is there a way?

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: This is eminently google-able. Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/file-system/how-to-write-to-a-text-file and maybe https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings, but if those are settings or parameters for your program, have a look at using Settings instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Please show us what your initial data looks like and what you want as the result.

Comment: Hello @HamishSmith, promise that I have Googled, what I need is to read the values from the txt and then save them to a string. But I want the txt to have more info and not to be only on line divided with a ";" like a format, so after I could know that value to change (if I need to) and know wich one. I´ll take a look on the links you re giving me :)

Comment: If you want a library than can automatically serialize and deserialize data into a string I would use JSON. There are libraries that will actually deserialize object types as well

Comment: or XML files too

Comment: Hello @CodingYoshi , I have a txt file from where I´m reading some values and save them to a specific string. My inicial txt file looks like this: Joe;Rodriguez;C:\example\hello.txt;398663

It is saving the the values separated with (;) sign, but the final result that I want is that insted of having one line separated with (;) sign on my txt file is to have like a format:

name = Joe
lastname = Rodriguez
path = C:\example\hello.txt
num = 398663

each value in one line and have a reference before the actual value I want to save. for example name = Joe (only save Joe to a variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reading in a line at a time and then calling `split` on the string contained by that line.

What you can do instead is separate out the variable in the text file by line, then assign the contents of each line to a different variable in each iteration of the loop.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about. It uses a dictionary so you can iterate through your variables.

Try this:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> myVars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            split = line.Split(new Char[] { '=' });
            myVars.Add(split[0], split[1]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Split 0 is: " + myVars["name"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Split 2 is: " + myVars["lastname"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Split 3 is: " + myVars["path"]);
        Console.WriteLine("Split 4 is: " + myVars["num"]);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

A downside to this approach is that in order to use non-string variables, you'll have to convert them but that shouldn't be too hard.

This example also requires your txt file to be formatted like this:

```
name=Joe
lastname=Rodriguez
path=C:\example\hello.txt
num=398663
```

Comment: Hello @Simon, this is actually what I was looking for, I have a nice format on my txt file instead of one line (proper to edit in the future) and I don´t have to open the code to edit some variable´s value. Nice! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments to your question you said:

> I have a txt file from where I´m reading some values and save them to a specific string. My inicial txt file looks like this: Joe;Rodriguez;C:\example\hello.txt;398663 It is saving the the values separated with (;) sign, but the final result that I want is that insted of having one line separated with (;) sign on my txt file is to have like a format: name = Joe lastname = Rodriguez path = C:\example\hello.txt num = 398663 each value in one line

Here is how you can read the file and then produce the output the way you want it:

```
using (var output = new StreamWriter("Output.txt"))
{
    foreach (var thisLine in File.ReadLines("Input.txt"))
    {
        var splits = thisLine.Split(';');
        output.WriteLine($"name = {splits[0]}");
        output.WriteLine($"lastname = {splits[1]}");
        output.WriteLine($"path = {splits[2]}");
    }
}
```